# why not display two picture in text?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, text, image

When I type S in text1 a corresponding picture appears in text2 however when I type G in text1 a corresponding  picture is shown in text2, but the previous picture of S is shown as a letter instead of a picture. Why is that? Why can't it display two pictures? What's wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText te1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1); 
        final EditText te2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t2); 



        final Button v = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);     
     v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
                //imva.setImageResource(R.id.b1);

                te2.setText(" ");

                String t= te1.getText().toString();

                char [] aa = t.toString().toCharArray(); 
                  for (int i = 0 ; i < aa.length ; i++)
                  {
                      if (aa[i] == 's')
                      {
                     SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(te1.getText());

                     do {
                ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(getBaseContext(),R.drawable.a1);  
                int pos = builder.toString().indexOf("s");
                builder.replace(pos, pos + 1, "$");
                 builder.setSpan(imageSpan, pos, pos + 1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
              } while (builder.toString().indexOf("s") > -1);
                    te2.setText(builder);

                      }  
                    if (aa[i] == 'g')
                    {           
                 SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(te1.getText());
                     do {
                    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(getBaseContext(),R.drawable.a2);  
                    int pos = builder.toString().indexOf("g");
                    builder.replace(pos, pos+ 1, "$");
                 builder.setSpan(imageSpan, pos, pos + 1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
              } while (builder.toString().indexOf("g") > -1);
                te2.setText(builder);

                      }  
                  }
```

Comment: **i think that the problem in this line** 

     te2.setText(builder);

**see if the input was a letters i would just use this line** 
 
   

     te2.setText(te2.getText().toString() + builder);  

**and let it continuo but the builder is not letters 
what should i replace it with !!!**

Comment: You are replacing *either* S *or* G in each step, and starting over from plain text at each occurrence.

Comment: Try replacing the `do` - `while` cycles by `while`, so you don't need to care whether the condition was ever met to start with. You can then drop the `if`s. Finally, get rid of the `for` cycle as you don't need it at all - the `while`s will take care of finding all occurrences already, you're doing that twice. So, just define the builder once, perform one replacement, perform the other, set text. Should do what you want.

Comment: the condition and the loop works fine the only problem is when the second picture is added the first return to be a letter

Comment: If you don't trust me and won't even try, I can't help. By defining a new SpannableStringBuilder in each iteration of the for loop, you drop the images you have already inserted and start over from a plain text te1.getText(). The computer just does what your program says.

Comment: @ Vašek Potoček sorry if it came out wrong what i meant is that  i did try what you said i replaced the do while with while but it crashed so i added it back again i am trying every thing i can get i just hope it will work already